# Why Java request object doesn't set attribute

Tags: html, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

everyone.

I'm having this problem: I'm getting key and value of hash map and I try to publish them on JSP:

```
for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        request.setAttribute("key", key);
        request.setAttribute("value", map.get(key));
}
request.getRequestDispatcher("/response.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

But when I try to get values in .jsp it's just doesn't send anything. I've tried to replace key with string and it didn't send it. Here's JSP code:

```
 <% request.getParameter("key"); %> means <% request.getParameter("value"); %>
```

Solved it: The problem was I've never called post method.

Comment: You should use getAttribute on the request instead of getParameter.

Comment: Any change has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use getAttribute method in your response.jsp file.

```
<% request.getAttribute("key"); %> means <% request.getAttribute("value"); %>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, it didn't change nothing. Do I need session?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are iterating a map, but you are storing the keys and the values using the same "key" in the request, so only the last one will be kept.

Also, you are using `setAttribute`, so you should use `getAttribute` to obtain any object you added.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed about iteration problem. But with getAttribute I don't pass value too.

Comment: Is any error shown? Or just null? Session is not needed, by the way.

Comment: No. It's just null. It just prints "mean" on screen.